# Calendar wiped out on iPad 4th Generation

Tags: ipad, calendar

I have an iPad (4th Generation) I just went to check my calendar and everything is gone. I don't have cloud back up because I don't have a recent enough Windows OS on my PC.

I just noticed that all the info seems to have been transferred to my iPhone. Is there a way to get it back to my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, what accounts are listed in Settings > Mail, Contacts and Calendars? Check this on both devices. Do any of the accounts have Calendar turned in?

If both devices are running iOS 5 or later (which your iPad definitely is), you can simply sign into iCloud and let the information sync across.

Comment: On my iPhone I have iCloud (which I don't have up and running because of my outdated windows OS on my pc) but it is set to on. Also on my phone is a gmail account.on my ipad I have the same 2 accounts but both have the calendar shut off. I can't imagine why everything would move from my ipad to my iPhone.

Comment: iCloud does depend on Windows, so that should be ok. Before turning iCloud on, on the iPhone go to the Calendar app, Groups, and note what calendar accounts are showing up. Use a process of elimination to determine what "calendar" your events are on, and then enable that calendar in your iPad